# An array value empty although previously populated

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm am sure this is a silly mistake but I have been staring at this the past 20mins to
no avail. I have an array `balance[]` that is populated with two values for `balance[0]`
and `balance[1]`. These are populated within the first for loop however when I go to use these values outside after this the array `balance[0]` is empty.

Below is my code and output:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++){

$x = mysql_query("

SELECT `outputValue` FROM `output` WHERE `outputType`= 'balance' && `period`= '6' && teamID = '$ID[$i]'

")or die($x."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    // set ID's = to a variable and now get Outputs for each variable(teamID)

            $balance = array();


            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($x);
            echo $i." = I<br/>";
            $balance[$i] = $row['outputValue'];
            echo "Team ".$i."Balance = ".$balance[$i]."<br/>";

}
for ($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++){
echo "Team ".$i."Balance = ".$balance[$i]."<br/>";
}
```

[image]

Comment: please tag the language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the `$balance` inside of the loop. On each `for` loop iteration, the `$balance` value is rewritten with an empty `array()`.

On the first iteration, the `$balance` is set to an empty array, and then the `$balance[0]` is set.
On the second iteration, the `$balance` is set to an empty array again, and then the `$balance[1]` is set.

So, after the loop, the `$balance` will only contain one element at the index of `$counter-1`.

Comment: great thanks for the quick response, I'm fairly new to programming and tend to make these stupid mistakes! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Move the line

```
   $balance = array();
```

outside of the loop.